# Robots.txt and secret URL ?xx=xx

Tags: robots.txt

I have a different secret url with `?id=123`, `?id=567` or `example.com/123` and I need to block all these URLs except my homepage, but I have a problem with `Disallow: /*`: it only works with Google.

My first robots.txt (blocked by Google)

```
User-Agent: * 
Allow: /
Disallow: /$
```

Actually I have replaced `example.com/123` by `example.com/?id=123` because `$` did not work and I use

```
User-Agent: * 
Allow: /
Disallow: /?id=
```

I have added `meta`-`robots`

```
$robotIndex = "index,nofollow";
if(!empty($_GET)) {
    $robotIndex = "noindex,nofollow";
}
```

Is it correct? What is the syntax to disallow all pages except the homepage?

Comment: no matter what you put on the page or in a robots.txt file some bots will crawl any page they can find.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Google offered robots.txt testing tool in Webmaster Tools (Crawl section). You can add a rule and test a URL against it. That way you can test if your configuration works properly.

Also, under Crawl section, you have URL Parameters option. You can set how and if parameters in your URLs change the content of the page and if these URLs should be indexed.